# How to remove MouseCallback and close Window in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a settings window where the user can press a button to create a new window where you can select an area of an image. After the area is selected the user can press the right mouse button to save its coordinates in an xml file. This "select area" window should close automatically after the xml file was saved.

My problem is that i'm not able to call cv::destroyWindow on my new window without it crashing my whole program. I thought about removing the mouse event first with `setMouseCallback( "imageWindow", NULL, NULL );` but that didn't prevent the crashing.

Following are the important parts of my code:

```
void Settings::on_buttonXML_clicked(){
    cv::VideoCapture webcam;
    webcam.open(INDEX);    
    webcam.read(src);
    color = Scalar(0,0,255);
    coor_num = 0;
    xmlPath="C:/myregion.xml";
    cv::namedWindow("imageWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow("imageWindow", src);
    cv::setMouseCallback( "imageWindow", onMouse, this );
    cv::waitKey(0);
}

void Settings::onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void* userdata) {
    Settings* settings = reinterpret_cast<Settings*>(userdata);
    settings->onMouse(event, x, y);
}
void Settings::onMouse(int event, int x, int y) {
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP) {
        cv::Point2f p(x, y);
        coor.push_back(p);
        cv::line(src,p,p,color);
        if(coor.size()>1)
            cv::line(src, p, coor[coor.size()-2], color);
        cv::imshow("imageWindow", src);
    }
    else if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP && coor.size()>2){
        cv::line(src, coor[0], coor[coor.size()-1], color);
        getPointsInContour(coor);
        cv::imshow("imageWindow", src);
        cv::waitKey(500);
        cv::setMouseCallback( "imageWindow", NULL, NULL );
        cv::destroyWindow("imageWindow");
    }
}
void Settings::savePointsAsXML(vector<Point2f> & contour){
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    TiXmlDeclaration decl("1.0", "", "");
    doc.InsertEndChild(decl);
    for(int i = 0; i < contour.size(); i++)
    {
        TiXmlElement point("point");
        point.SetAttribute("x",contour[i].x);
        point.SetAttribute("y",contour[i].y);
        doc.InsertEndChild(point);
    }
    if(doc.SaveFile(xmlPath.c_str()))
        cout << "file saved succesfully.\n";
    else
        cout << "file not saved, something went wrong!\n";
}

void Settings::getPointsInContour(vector<Point2f> & contour){
    vector<Point2f> insideContour;
    for(int j = 0; j < src.rows; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < src.cols; i++){
            Point2f p(i,j);
            if(pointPolygonTest(contour,p,false) >= 0) // yes inside
                insideContour.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    cout << "# points inside contour: " << insideContour.size() << endl;
    savePointsAsXML(insideContour);
}
```

I think the problem might be with `cv::waitKey(0);` in my `Settings::on_buttonXML_clicked()` function. I'm not really sure why I need to call `waitKey(0)` there but I know that I will crash immediately if waitKey() isn't there or its parameter is above 0. What am I missing here?